# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle two login form error configure the check path

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

i need to have 2 login form.

1 -> main site
2 -> my backend

i have see many thread for this.

I try to do it, but i have an error : 
**"You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration."**

But it's set in security.yml

My route is ok, my form is ok, and i don't see where is my error.

**This is my security.yml**

```
admin_login:
        context: backend
        pattern: ^/th-admin/login
        anonymous: true

    admin_check:
        context: backend
        pattern: ^/th-admin/login_check
        anonymous: true

    admin_access_denied:
        context: backend
        pattern: ^/th-admin/access_denied
        anonymous: true

    admin:
        context: backend
        pattern: ^/th-admin

        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            #use_referer: true # this is not needed if you always use default target
            #always_use_default_target_path: true
            #default_target_path: th_admin_dashboard
            login_path: th_admin_login
            check_path: th_admin_check

        logout:
            path:   th_admin_logout
            target: th_admin_login
        anonymous: false
        access_denied_url: th_admin_denied




    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/th-admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/th-admin/access_denied, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/th-admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**This is my fos_user configuration :**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: TH\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

**This is my custom form :**

```
            {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}


        <form class="m-t" role="form" method="post" action="{{ path("th_admin_check") }}">

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'admin.login.email'|trans }}" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'admin.login.password'|trans }}" required="">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_submit" value="Login" />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">{{ 'admin.login.login'|trans }}</button>

        </form>
```

**This is my routes :**

```
th_admin_denied:
    path:     /access_denied
    defaults: { _controller: THAdminBundle:Default:accessDenied }

th_admin_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

th_admin_check:
    path:     /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

th_admin_logout:
    path:     /logout
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }

th_admin_dashboard:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: THAdminBundle:Dashboard:index }
```

I have try to clear cache, hard clear cache (empty folder with rm -rf)

When i set the other check url, this work but this go to the main firewall.
The main firewall work.
But my admin backend firewall doesn't work...

Anyone know where is my error ?

Thx

Comment: Maybe post the route for th_admin_check?  I'm used to seeing "anonymous: ~" instead of "anonymous: false".  Once you get past the check problem then you may have some csrf issues as well.

Comment: I have tried for the anonymous parameter but this not work too. i have completed my post. Thx for your reply.

Comment: I think your route paths are wrong.  "path: /login_check" should be "path:     /th-admin/login_check".  Just guessing.  Not used to seeing all those firewalls defined or using context.  If you still have problems then maybe revert your security.yml to the default example, get things working then add the firewalls back in.

Comment: To be sure, have you tried to add explicitly the `login_access` route on access control like this: `- { path: ^/th-admin/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` to see if it works? If not try to modify also the main admin root like this: `- { path: ^/th-admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` and `- { path: ^/th-admin/$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` instead of `- { path: ^/th-admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }`

Comment: I set anonymous to false for my admin firewall, so i need other firewall for authorize anounymous in sub path. i read this, and this work. i can access my login page, access_denied page, and other page redirect to login page. if i set anonymous to true, this doesn't work too. My route is ok, i have prefix with 'th-admin'. It's ok because, the checkAction in page controller is executed. this is the problem. if the config work, this checkAction don't be executed. the request need to be handled before. (sorry, i don't speak english very well.)
gp_sflover : I have try but doesn't work too.

Comment: it's ok. i have problem with the firewall right you say. I write my answer thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is the firewall configuration.

Need to have an order in access_control and does'nt create useless firewall.
Thx all for your reply.

This is the good configuration :

```
firewalls:

    admin_firewall:
        pattern: ^/th-admin

        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            #use_referer: true # this is not needed if you always use default target
            #always_use_default_target_path: true
            #default_target_path: th_admin_dashboard
            login_path: th_admin_login
            check_path: th_admin_check

        logout:
            path:   th_admin_logout
            target: th_admin_login
        anonymous: ~
        access_denied_url: th_admin_denied


    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true


access_control:
    - { path: /th-admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /th-admin/access_denied, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/th-admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/th-admin/$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```